# Use fetch with another domain

Tags: javascript, web, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to `fetch` an HTML page, in my case a page from a GitHub Wiki.

Here is my code

```
fetch(url, {
    mode: 'cors'
}).then(data => data.text()).then(data => {
    ...
})
```

But I'm getting

> [Error] Fetch API cannot load https://github.com/arguiot/KiwiDocs/wiki. Origin https://localhost:5757 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've looked for a working solution, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: It is not possible, because you can not control the Github server configuration and they do not allow CORS. Hence, you will need to set up a proxy, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere could be helpful

Comment: @dirkk So I definitely can't get the content of this page without using a server? Even using another method?

Comment: You can use online services like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ so you don't have to setup a proxy yourself. But apart from this, no. Also note that this is not a bug, but a specifically designed feature for browser security.

Comment: @dirkk But can I use that with a lot of users. I'm thinking of at least 1 request per seconds (without counting refresh, etc...)